# JavaFX 8 'fx:constant' causes a parse error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx, fxml, efxclipse

I am trying to load in FXML for my JavaFX application and am receiving this exception:

```
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
~/eclipse/javafx-test/target/classes/fxml/TestApplication.fxml:52

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2543)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$2700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$IncludeElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1143)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:746)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at com.example.Main.start(TestApplication.java:12)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)

Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[52,37]
Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributePrefixUnbound?Cursor&fx:constant&fx
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:596)
at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:88)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2513)    ... 20 more
```

The FXML lines causing this are:

```
<cursor>
    <Cursor fx:constant="DEFAULT" />
</cursor>
<columnResizePolicy>
    <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
</columnResizePolicy>
```

I am using JavaFX 8 in Eclipse Neon with the e(fx)clipse plugin.
Thank you if you can help.

Comment: Have you added the namespace declaration? Please show the root element of the fxml file.

Comment: Wow that fixed it, thanks @fabian.
For people coming with the same problem: I added `xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"` to my root element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had forgotten to add the proper namespace to my root element.

`xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"` add those to your root and this is solved.